# Python to change image into a color that is Not one of the image's dominant colors

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library

[red yellow apple][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH8av.png

I would like to change this image of an apple (RGBA) .png into one color that is not one of the top 4 colors that are mainly in this image.

Possible colors the image could be changed into:

```
R= (255, 0 , 0) #bright red
G= (0, 204, 0) #light green
B= (0, 145, 255) #sky blue
O= (255, 154, 0) #orange
V = (0, 204, 0) #light violet
```

The top 3 main colors in this image are:

- (162, 25, 17)
- (252, 222, 155)
- (214, 89, 40)

I want to recolor the image into 1 of those 5 options that are not close to these top 3 colors.

**Where I am stuck at**: recolor the image into 1 of those 5 options that are NOT **close to these top 3 colors**

I've attached part of my code below

```
import glob, os
import random

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageColor, ImageEnhance           # PIL = Pillow


#====================================
def main():
    global mask_image
    alphabet = []
    
    #for later (randomly pick R, G, B, O as main color)
    R= (255, 0 , 0) #bright red
    G= (0, 204, 0) #light green
    B= (0, 145, 255) #sky blue
    O= (255, 154, 0) #orange
    V = (0, 204, 0) #light violet if needed


    image = Image.open("apple1.png")
    image.show() #before edit
    
    image.convert("RGBA") #make sure to convert

    #getting color values
    colorValues = image.getdata()
#       colorValues = image.getcolors(maxcolors=256) #returns tuple of R, G, B color values
    print("color Values = ", colorValues, "\n\n")

    #figure out main colors via MeanShift or Fast octree
    mainColors = image.quantize(colors = 4, method =2) #using fast octree
    print("main colors = ", mainColors.getpalette()[:12], "\n\n") #4 main colors in image
                                                                    #first is alpha?

    #get image size
    w, h = image.size

    #change to random color (bonus points if can change to color that isn't main color)

        
    blank_image = Image.new('RGBA', (w,h), (0, 0, 0, 0)) #transparent image same size as image
    
    #set alpha value to .5
    out_image = Image.blend(blank_image, image, .7)
    out_image.show()


#===============================================================

# extra stuff needed to make Pyton run like C with a main() function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to change the colours is to swap the channels of an image, so exchange say the red and blue channels, so that redness in the original image shows up as blueness in the processed image:

```
from PIL import Image

# Load the image
im = Image.open('apple.png').convert('RGBA')

# Split into its constituent channels
R, G, B, A = im.split()

# Now make a new image with Red and Blue channels interchanged
new = Image.merge('RGBA', (B,G,R,A))
```

[image]

Or re-ordering with:

```
new = Image.merge('RGBA', (G,B,R,A))
```

[image]

Or, re-ordering with:

```
new = Image.merge('RGBA', (B,R,G,A))
```

[image]

---

Actually, you can achieve exactly the same effect as above, and other more sophisticated effects maybe somewhat more elegantly with a *"matrix"* parameter to the `convert()` function. So, this swaps the red and blue using matrix multiplication. The comments explain what is going on:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Open image, save alpha channel and convert to RGB
im = Image.open('apple.png').convert('RGBA')
alpha = im.getchannel('A')

im = im.convert('RGB')

# Make transform matrix, to swap Red and Blue channels
# Understand values like this:
#
# NewRed   =  0 * OldRed   + 0 * OldGreen    + 1 *OldBlue   + 0 offset, i.e. newRed   = OldBlue
# NewGreen =  0 * OldRed   + 0 * OldGreen    + 0 *OldBlue   + 0 offset, i.e. newGreen = OldGreen
# NewBlue  =  1 * OldRed   + 0 * OldGreen    + 0 *OldBlue   + 0 offset, i.e. newBlue  = Old Red
Matrix = ( 0, 0, 1, 0,
           0, 1, 0, 0,
           1, 0, 0, 0)

# Apply above transform, reinsert alpha and save 
im = im.convert("RGB", Matrix)
im.putalpha(alpha)
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

Here's another option...

Have a read about [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) colourspace. You will learn that Hue roughly corresponds to what most people call *"colour"*, Saturation refers to what most people call *"vividness"* and Value is just how bright/dark something is.

So, you basically want to change Hue, without affecting Saturation and Value and also without affecting your alpha/transparency channel.

- load image
- extract alpha channel and save for later
- convert to HSV
- split channels, put S and V aside for later
- take H channel and process it being sure to wrap around at 255 because it is circular. I chose to add 120, but you could add 60, or subtract 160, or whatever you want.
- recombine new H with original S and V
- push in original alpha channel
- save and admire result

Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
    
from PIL import Image
    
# Load image, save alpha channel
im = Image.open('apple.png').convert('RGBA')
alpha = im.getchannel('A')

# Make HSV version and split into separate channels
HSV = im.convert('RGB').convert('HSV')
H, S, V = HSV.split()

# Choose our amount of Hue rotation
R = 120
newH = H.point(lambda p: (p+R) % 255)

# Recombine processed H, S and V back into a recombined image
HSVr = Image.merge('HSV', (newH,S,V))
# Convert recombined HSV back to reconstituted RGB, reinsert saved alpha
RGBr = HSVr.convert('RGB')
RGBr.putalpha(alpha)
RGBr.show()
```

[image]

Comment: These are beautiful solutions. Thanks, Mark! This path is much nicer than what I had in mind, and the result is even better than just putting a one color mask on top.